# Is mycomparison a object , function or function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I was going through following code:

```
template <typename String>
void test_decimals()
{
  SensibleLessThan<String> mycomparison;
  String lhs = "1.212";
  String rhs = "1.234";
  CHECK_EQUAL(mycomparison(lhs, rhs), true); // CHECK EQUAL is macro

}
```

I do not understand the meaning of the following constructs:

- `SensibleLessThan<String> mycomparison;`
- `mycomparison(lhs, rhs)`

Is `mycomparison` an object, a function or a function pointer?

Answer (score 8):

`SensibleLessThan<String>` is a type. `mycomparison` is an object of that type. Now it appears that the type overloads `operator()`, which allows it to be called as though it were a function. Objects of such types are usually known as *function objects* or *functors*. Such objects are, like functions, considered *callable*.

For a simple example, here's an `adder` struct that overloads `operator()`. We can create an object of the `adder` type and then use that object as though it were a function.

```
#include <iostream>

struct adder
{
  int operator()(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
};

int main()
{
  adder my_adder;
  std::cout << my_adder(5, 6) << std::endl;
}
```

[Here it is in action](http://ideone.com/VQiDTn). In fact, a similar type already exists in the C++ standard library: [`std::plus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus).

Comment: Of course, it might be possible to make the template match function pointers too.

Comment: is that means , SensibleLessThan is a struct with template ?

Comment: @user2321447 `SensibleLessThan` is either a template class or template struct. Both classes and structs can overload `operator()`. I only used a struct here to avoid writing `public:`.